# Чтение файла из treeView в Richtextbox?

Tags: c#, treeview, richtextbox

Делаю программу, в которой `treeView` выводит список файлов согласно условию.
Файлы формата `.rtf`.

Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на файл, он открывался в `Richtextbox`?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication6
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }



        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo("D://В машиностроении");
            foreach (FileInfo files in dir.GetFiles())
            {
                treeView1.Nodes.Add(files.Name);
            }
        }



        private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        }
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/3f99sst7(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Получится не очень быстро, но как способ реализации может подойти.

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string  Temppath { get; set; }
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        treeView1.AfterSelect += TreeView1_AfterSelect;
        Temppath = "D://В машиностроении\\";
    }
    private void TreeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        this.richTextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(Temppath, e.Node.FullPath));

    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(Temppath);
        TreeNode node = new TreeNode();
        GetDirectorys(dirInfo, node);
        foreach(TreeNode n in node.Nodes)
        {
            this.treeView1.Nodes.Add(n);
        }
    }
    private void GetDirectorys(DirectoryInfo d, TreeNode node)
    {
        DirectoryInfo[] dInfo = d.GetDirectories();
        if (dInfo == null || dInfo.Length == 0)
        {
            FileInfo[] fInfo = d.GetFiles();
            TreeNode treeNode = new TreeNode();
            foreach (FileInfo fDir in fInfo)
            {
                treeNode = node.Nodes.Add(fDir.Name);
            }
        }            
        if (dInfo.Length > 0)
        {
            TreeNode treeNode = new TreeNode();
            foreach (DirectoryInfo driSub in dInfo)
            {
                treeNode = node.Nodes.Add(driSub.Name);
                GetDirectorys(driSub, treeNode);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. Могут быть проблемы с кодировкой.

Comment: Необработанное исключение типа "System.NotImplementedException" в WindowsFormsApplication6.exe

Comment: @Masik164 В каком именно месте вылетает?